# как программно на си шарп закрыть звуковой файл с расширением m4a?

Tags: c#

после того как запущен звуковой файл с помощью Process.Start("D:\prg.m4a") как  программно закрыть его ?

Comment: [Process.Kill Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: если именно *закрыть* -- [Process.Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не самая тривиальная задача, вам нужно или заранее определять при помощи какого exe открывать этот файл или же каким-то образом искать процесс который этот файл занимает и уже его закрывать.

Comment: Никак не закрыть. Вы не можете знать, что запустит операционная система этой строчкой. Будет это 1 процесс или 100? 1 окно или 100 окон? А может вообще запустится вирус какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

Получаете экземпляр процесса при старте, потом, в случае необходимости, килляете этот процесс.

```
// запускаем и получаем экземпляр процесса
Process process = Process.Start("D:\prg.m4a");
// ждем 10 секунд
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
// килляем процесс
if (process != null)
    process.Kill(); // process.Close(); или process.CloseMainWindow(); как более гуманные варианты
else MessageBox.Show("Процесс не был запущен, т.к. файл не может быть открыт, либо был открыт ранее.");
```

Comment: `Process.Start` может вернуть `null`